# Could BingBot's case-insensitive url handling of my js files impact SEO?

Tags: seo, url, bing

BingBot loaded the root of my page, and the included JS. The JS url contains base64-encoded binary data, because hex was unnecessarily long. Singe BingBot requests all url's in lowercase, the base64 part of the url is destroyed, causing the request for the js file to fail with a 500 error.

Could this failed request cause worse SEO in Bing? Is it worth making the site a little heavier for all users and all other bots, to let BingBot avoid this 500? We're already the top result for close searches on Bing, but we don't top the results for the big traffic searches that are a bit further off yet.

Comment: I would assume that Bing is making a request exactly from the information they gathered. I would be looking to find how they got the resource link and making sure it is correct first. Bing does know that requests must be case sensitive so it would/should not modify them.

Comment: According to the log files, they (or app engine) lowercased it for this request. No other user agent has caused this error before.

Comment: Could be a Bing bug then. Generally, search engines have this stuff figured out and an error can be found somewhere else. I was just making sure. ;-)

Comment: Yeah, me too, before writing this question. It seemed unreal that Bing would miss something like this.

Comment: Hey!! Remember that Bing is Microsoft. I am not really surprised. Are you??